# Need help beginning C++ program

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I'm just starting to learn c++ i just want to ask how can I loop this? Please, don't give me direct answer give me a clue or just a "work frame" how to solve this problem. I want to solve it on my own.

So I'm kinda getting difficulties in looping decimals only i can loop solid numbers but i have some troubles looping decimal figures.

P.S Im reviewing for an exam 4 hours from now but this might come up, i having difficulties in this types of question.

This is the question:

Shipping Cost Calculator
A mail order company charges $3.00 for handling, free shipping for orders 10 pounds or less, plus $0.25 for each pound over 10. Write a program that repeatedly asks the user for the weight of an order, then writes out the shipping charge. The program stops when a weight of zero or less is entered.
Weight of Order:
5
Shipping Cost: $3.00
Weight of Order
20
Shipping Cost: $5.50
Weight of Order
0
bye

I keep on practicing to this but i seem to find error on a formula

how can I loop 3.25 to 4.50 to 5.75 to 6.00 and so on?

```
main() {
   float a, b, x;       

   printf("Enter Weight:     ");
   scanf("%f", &a);

   if (a <= 10)
   {
       printf("Your balance is 3.00");
   }
   else if (a > 10)      
   {  
      for (x =.25; x <= a; x++)
      {
          printf("Your balance is %.2f \n", a);
          a += + .25;      
      }
   }
   else if (a == 0)
   {
       printf("Bye");
   }           

    getche();
}
```

Comment: Please get a proper C++ book, the one you have is teaching you very, very wrong things: the code contains numerous trivial errors.

Comment: `main() {…}` is not valid C++.

Comment: Nope, i am self studying for an exam, but it might be ask.

Comment: main() needs a return type of int to be valid in C++. Try using int main() { ... return 0 }

Comment: 1. Where are the header includes? 2. You forgot the return type of `main()`: `int` 3. Don't pass a `float*` and tell `scanf` it's a `double*`. 4. Printing an indeterminate variable (`b`) is undefined behavior. 5. `getche()` is not a standard method. Don't you want to restrict yourself to the standard library for a start?

Answer (score 0):

```
for ( double x = 3.25; x <= so_on; x += 1.25 ) { /*...*/ }
```

or

```
for ( float x = 3.25f; x <= so_on; x += 1.25f ) { /*...*/ }
```